# How do I put HTML checkbox inside a list kind of a view

Tags: html, css

How do I put a list of checkboxes inside a list kind of a view, when rendering it should able to scroll down like when we can do it with

```
<select id="myselectlist" name="myselectlist" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="option 1">option 1</option>
</select>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an unordered list with list items containing checkboxes and labels. The unordered list would be styled with `overflow-y` set to `auto` and `height` set to some number of pixels.